# Error while querying hive table with map datatype in Spark SQL. But working while executing in HiveQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have hive table with below structure

```
+---------------+--------------+----------------------+
| column_value  | metric_name  |         key          |
+---------------+--------------+----------------------+
| A37B          | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"1"}  |
| ACCOUNT_ID    | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"2"}  |
| ANB_200       | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"3"}  |
| ANB_201       | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"4"}  |
| AS82_RE       | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"5"}  |
| ATTR001       | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"2"}  |
| ATTR001_RE    | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"3"}  |
| ATTR002       | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"4"}  |
| ATTR002_RE    | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"5"}  |
| ATTR003       | Mean         | {0:"202008",1:"3"}  |
| ATTR004       | Mean         | {0:"202008",1:"4"}  |
| ATTR005       | Mean         | {0:"202008",1:"5"}  |
| ATTR006       | Mean         | {0:"202009",1:"4"}  |
| ATTR006       | Mean         | {0:"202009",1:"5"}  |
```

I need to write a spark sql query to filter based on Key column with NOT IN condition with commination of both keys.

The following query works fine in HiveQL in Beeline

```
select * from your_data where key[0] between  '202006' and '202009' and key NOT IN ( map(0,"202009",1,"5") );
```

But when i try the same query in Spark SQL. I am getting error

> cannot resolve due to data type mismatch: map<int,string>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:115)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:107)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:277)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:275)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:275)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:324)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:275)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:275)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:275)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:326)

Please help!

Comment: Does `where key[0] between '202006' and '202009'` works better?

Comment: yes. That works fine. Error only when querying with combination of keys

Comment: i think its always better to convert explicitly and not trust the tool/engine to do it. can you pls cast everythign to BIGINT and try again - `CAST(key[0] to BIGINT) between  202006 and 202009` ?

Comment: Between is working fine. Issue is in this code `key NOT IN ( map(0,"202009",1,"5") )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from different question which i raised before. This query is working fine

`select * from your_data  where key[0] between  202006 and 202009 and NOT (key[0]="202009" and key[1]="5" );`